# OpenTok Session Delegate Callback Has nil Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTok to create a video conference between 2 iOS devices. I want to send information about a user (i.e. a userID) to the other member of the conference so once I get the callback that a user is connected, I send that connection that information:

```
//Start Call - Session is already created with a valid session ID.
-(void) startCall{
    OTError* error = nil;
    self.session connectWithToken:myToken error:&error];

    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Session signal Error: %@", error);
    }
}

//Session delegate methods
– (void) session:(OTSession*) session connectionCreated:(OTConnection*) connection{
    OTError* error = nil;
    [session signalWithType:@"UserInfo" string:self.user.userID connection:connection error:&error];

    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Session signal Error: %@", error);
    }
}

-(void) session:(OTSession*) session receivedSignalType:(NSString*) type fromConnection:(OTConnection*) connection withString:(NSString*) string{
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"UserInfo"]){
        self.remoteUser.userID = string;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in some cases, the `OTConnection` I bet back in the `– session:receivedSignalType:fromConnection:withString:` is `nil`. Not only that but when I put a breakpoint in that callback my local session's connection is also `nil`. I assume this means that my local session is not connected yet when I receive that signal but I wouldn't have thought it was possible to receive a signal if my local session is not connected. Additionally I don't send the signal until the connection is created, so how is it `nil` on the other device?

Has anyone else seen this or come up with a way to prevent it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: what i have to pass for self.user.userID value.Please help me

Comment: You have two client applications and you are connecting to tokbox from both of them. As soon as you are connected, you signal a user ID from both devices to each other. Now you are not receiving this signal on other device. Is this the issue? And since this is a pretty old thread, have you got the issue resolved?